# abi.encode transfer question

Tags: solidity, smart-contract

If I make a call to an external smart contract that uses a function (transfer) which of the following is safer.

1. **using abi.encodeWithSignature**

```
(bool success, ) = address(contractInstance).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(address, uint256)", msg.sender, amount));
require(success, "Failed to send tokens");
```

2. **direct call**

```
contractInstance.transfer(msg.sender, amount)
```

for both im using reentrancy guard.

Thanks!

Comment: the only safe way is to check the balance after the transfer, it must be equal to `balanceBefore + amountTransferred` , everything else is unsafe. A token can report transfer as successful via event but don't really transfer anything. you have to add `balanceOf()` call (and spend more gas). Check out , for example, the `flash()` function of UniswapV3Pool contract, this is 100% safe

Comment: That’s interesting. Definitely will check. Thanks

Comment: Are the two codes the same think? I am confused, looks that the first is calling "transfer" function as member of address type, and the second is calling "transfer" as a function of the contract with possible arbitrary implementation. Anyway, the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related) says to avoid ".call()", so i recomend use the second way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both do the same thing but the second is suggested cause it's simpler, so less error-prone.

As @Nulik said, when dealing with unknown ERC20 tokens there can be other risks. Check [this blog](https://soliditydeveloper.com/safe-erc20) for examples.